# Insert a formula with string variables in a cell using vba

Tags: excel, vba, string

I've set a Date variable to workday -2

I'm using a String to format that Date variable using `format(date, "mm/yyyy")`

I'm trying to add this String variable into a formula and I'm pasting into an excel cell using VBA but still, it adds quotations around my String variable so the formula doesn't work.

e.g Range("Z2:Z" & Lastrow).formula = "=vlookup(y2, filename_""" & Date Name & """.xlsx"

I'm currently double quoting my string variable within the formula as a single quote leads to an error.

I'm expecting the date to show up in the formula without being surrounded by quotation marks

Comment: Please edit your Q to include  an example  of _exactly_ what you want your pasted formula to be, and which parts of it are to be created from variables.

Comment: Please provide the code you are trying to use, because is a little hard to get what you really want. I will try to do something meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

The triple double quotes are concatenating a double quote to your string.

Change

> ```
>  Range("Z2:Z" & Lastrow).formula = "=vlookup(y2, filename_""" & Date Name & """.xlsx"
> ```

to

> ```
>  Range("Z2:Z" & Lastrow).formula = "=vlookup(y2, filename_" & Date Name & ".xlsx"
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply TinMan

Would you know what I can do to just have the variable without the quotations?

Single quotes, I get an error
double quotes, the formula shows DateName
triple quotes, I get my intended result but with quotation marks

Comment: never mind! your fix worked! The first time I tried single quotes, I kept getting the error 'object defined error' but now it seems to be working. 

Thank you for your help!